# Dynamically mark a multiple select with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, select

I'm trying to mark a multiple select I have with dinamic data i receive from a ajax function.
The data is ok, its coming as an array, but i can't set it to the select values.
Follow the photos and the code.
The pic below is my multiple select.
[image]

The pic below is the data i'm receiving:

[image]

**And what I tried until now:**
json.idChaveDepartamento is the data i'm receiving, i'm splitting it.

```
let idChaveDepartamento = json.idChaveDepartamento.split(',');
$('#Departamento').selectpicker('val', idChaveDepartamento);
```

or

```
let idChaveDepartamento = json.idChaveDepartamento.split(',');
$("#Departamento").val(idChaveDepartamento);
```

or even tried to copy/paste a function I found on the internet

```
let select = document.getElementById('Departamento');

  function in_array(needle, haystack, argStrict){

    var key = '', strict = !!argStrict;
    if (strict){
        for (key in haystack){
            if (haystack[key] === needle)
                return true;
        }
    }
    else{
       for (key in haystack){
            if (haystack[key] == needle)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
if (select) {
   for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++){
        //Select options matching array values, unselect others
        select.options[i].selected = in_array(select.options[i].value, idChaveDepartamento, false);
    }
}
```

But unfortunately nothing works. The data i'm receiving have the same value of the select option.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For those who see this question and have the same problem, i was able to solve this with the following code:

```
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect" >
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>


<script>
const select = document.getElementById('mySelect');

const array = [1,2,3,4];

for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
    select.options[i].selected = array.indexOf(departamento.options[i].value) >= 0;
}
</script>
```

this will iterate the atribute **SELECTED** of the multiple select, and will add one by one

Comment: this does not solve the problem with "multiple" select, as stated in title

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response. Ok, feel free to post your solution below :)